# Create one trigger for all sobject types

Tags: apex, trigger

I wants to create trigger which will run on all sobjects.
Something like

```
Trigger myTrigger on Sobject(after insert){}
```

Answer (score 6):

That is not possible both in terms of the syntax and the functionality you are trying to achieve. There are a lot of sObjects out there that don't support triggers.

What you could do is create a class that operates on the generic sObject, and have a bunch of individual triggers call that class.

Class

```
public class Trigger_SObject {
    public static void doSomething(list<SObject> TriggerNew){
        for (SObject so : TriggerNew) system.debug(so.get('Name'));
    }
}
```

Trigger (make one for each object you want the code to act on)

```
trigger Account on Account(after update) {
    Trigger_SObject.doSomething( (list<SObject>) Trigger.new );
}
```

Comment: For sure i already planned to do what you suggest.. Just wonder exist such a way.. thanks

Comment: Probably would be good to implement some sort of handler cache, e.g. `Map<SObjectType, TriggerHandler>`.